# What should i choose for command like application between Ruby or python

Tags: python, ruby, command-line-interface

This is very first I am writing command line tool apps. Apps has few custom command which forks a repo from github and CD's into it. Command can also submit new code and rise new pull request. There might be also some application login before submit/pull-request also.

After few research i found , there are serval options such as 
 - Bash 
 - **Ruby**
 - python

(i know python but don't have any problem learning ruby as well. It hard to write business logic in Bash, so bash is not i am looking for)

Ruby seems to be more rich when it come to command like tool. Thor 
is a famous lib for doing this in ruby

Python can also do same stuff with command line with Cement Framework and click.

Wanted to know which one is preferred when it comes to writing command line apps like this.

Comment: I would do it in ruby - others will do it in their preferred language. Want to learn something new and have fun? Then why not learn ruby - its fit for the job. Want to get the thing done? - use the language you know best. Unfortunately your question is too broad and the answers will definately be oppinion based. Both ruby and python (and many other) programming languages are totally valid choices with preference upon the implementer.

Comment: https://github.com/learn-co/learn-co wanted to do something like this. These people have chosen ruby

Comment: I'm partial to Ruby myself, but if you already know Python then you should probably use Python. When it comes to command-line scripts, you can expect both Ruby and Python to be equally as capable. The answer to your question will depend on which language's syntax you prefer.

Comment: @brianjason right , thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

**Both work just fine.**

I would prefer python because it is easy to deploy. But the main take-away is [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html).

> The Cmd class provides a simple framework for writing line-oriented command interpreters. These are often useful for test harnesses, administrative tools, and prototypes that will later be wrapped in a more sophisticated interface.

But I'm pretty sure Ruby has something like that as well. So, people who knows Ruby better, can use Ruby.